# how to disable dates from data- passed in as a string

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making use of the bootstrap datepicker 1.4.0

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

What Im trying to do is block out certain days, that comes in via a string.

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="date-selector" data-dates-disabled="1,3,5>
$("input.date-selector").datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', orientation : 'left', todayHighlight : true, autoClose: true, clearBtn: true}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {$(this).datepicker('hide');});
```

By making use of the data-dates-disabled attribute as we are passing in a string of the days to be blocked out.

```
$("input.date-selector").datepicker({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', orientation : 'left', todayHighlight : true, autoClose: true, clearBtn: true, datesDisabled: $(this).attr('data-dates-disabled')}).on('changeDate', function (ev) {$(this).datepicker('hide');});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Check date on `onSelect` event of datepicker and make it empty if date selected is from `data-date-disabled` values

```
$("input.date-selector").datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
      orientation : 'left', 
      todayHighlight : true, 
      autoClose: true, 
      clearBtn: true, 
      datesDisabled: $(this).attr('data-dates-disabled'),
      onSelect : function(){
         var dateToDisable =  $(this).attr('data-dates-disabled').split(',');
         var date = parseInt($(this).val().split('/')[1]);
         if(dateToDisable.indexOf(date.toString())!=-1)
            $(this).val('');
      }
 }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {$(this).datepicker('hide');});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/obawc4zw/20/)**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the resolution by simplying applying the following

`days-of-week-disabled="1,2,4,5,6,7"` attribute